# LinkedIn V2 API return not found when called from Azure API Management

Tags: azure, linkedin-api, azure-api-management

I am trying to call LinkedIn V2 API from Azure API Management, specifically the ugcPost API:
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts

When the ugcPost API is called from our personal computer, the API is able to return the response successfully. However, when we attempt to call the ugcPost from Azure API Management, it responds back with status 404 (Resource not found).

```
{
  "serviceErrorCode": 0,
  "message": "Resource ugcPosts does not exist",
  "status": 404
}
```

Has anyone faced similar issue? Is there something in the LinkedIn Developer portal that we have to tweak for this to work?

Comment: Please add more details about your Azure API Management settings, such as Web service URL, Web API URL suffix, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it is an issue with the URL configuration that somehow append my base API URL causing the final URL to be incorrect (e.g. https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts/v2/ugcPosts).

After some URL reconfiguration, it is working fine now.